# jQuery: get result from genderAPI

Tags: jquery, api

I am using the [genderAPI](https://gender-api.com/en/api-docs) with `jQuery` for my project.

I am trying to get the gender result of `#name` but it seems like my code is not recognising it at all (no `alert` is jumping out). Would someone kindly suggest why please?

The `jQuery plugin` example they provided is below:

```
$('input#firstname').genderApi({key: genderApiClientKey}).on('gender-found', function(e, result) {

  if (result.accuracy >= 60) {    
    alert('Gender found: ' + result.gender);  
  }

});
```

Below is my attempt and you may find the full code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cklkaren/rokvowjv/18/):

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://gender-api.com/js/jquery/gender.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="fetch">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter your name here" id="term" />
        <button type="button" id="search">ENTER</button>
    </section>

    <div id="name">
        <div id="nameBox">
        </div>
        <div id="nameText">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

jQuery:

```
var apiUrl = "https://sheetsu.com/apis/f924526c"; // this is another API I created on Google Spreadsheet

$.getJSON(apiUrl, function (json) {

    console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
    var item = json.result.find(function (e) {

        return e.name == content;

    }) || json.result[0];
    console.log("PRINT ID: " + item.id);


    var name = item.name || content;
    var $nameText = $("#nameText"),
        str = name;
    html = $.parseHTML(str),
        nodeNames = [];
    $nameText.append(html);
    console.log("Name: " + name);

    // genderAPI here to get gender result
    $('name').genderApi({
        key: "oyxLJkutVSYXWNVzGP"
    }).on('gender-found', function (e, result) {
        if (result.accuracy >= 60) {
            alert('Gender found: ' + result.gender);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying execute genderAPI for below text field?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Please enter your name here" id="term" />
```

then your code should be like this:

```
   $('input#term').genderApi({
        key: "oyxLJkutVSYXWNVzGP"
    }).on('gender-found', function (e, result) {
        if (result.accuracy >= 60) {
            alert('Gender found: ' + result.gender);
        }
    });
```